# Django Rest Framework OneToOneField related BooleanFilter

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using django with rest-framework.

Now I have models with OneToOne relations:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(
        A, related_name='b')
```

And I have a ViewSet applied on A:

```
class ModelAViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer
```

Then, I want to add a `BooleanFilter` on `ModelAViewSet` to filter whether the `ModelA` object has a relating `ModelB` object.

And I tried the below:

```
class ModelAViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    class Filter(FilterSet):
        has_b = filters.BooleanFilter('b')
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer
    filter_fields = ['has_b']
```

So, if it works, we got:

1. `?has_b=1`: returning all records without filtering;
2. `?has_b=2`: returning records which have relating `ModelA` object;
3. `?has_b=3`: returning records which **NO NOT** have relating `ModelA` object;

It almost worked, except the case 3 above.

So what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why are you passing a number to a boolean filter?

Comment: I passes the related OneToOneField which is not a boolean result at all, may be I should make a queryset lookup string, but I can find the solution.

Comment: @Sayse The default widget is django's [NullBooleanSelect](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/forms/widgets.py#L561-L589), which uses these choices. If you're using the latest version of django-filter, then you can do the following instead: `from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet, filters`. The `BooleanFilter` in the sub-package uses a custom `BooleanWidget` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet, filters

class Filter(FilterSet):
    has_b = filters.BooleanFilter(name='b', lookup_expr='isnull', exclude=True)
```

There are three changes here:

1. By importing from the `rest_framework` sub-package, an API-friendly `BooleanWidget` is used, so you can query `?has_b=true` instead of `?has_b=1`.
2. The filter is using an `isnull` lookup, which allows you to test for existence of a related model.
3. `b__isnull=True` is testing for the *lack* of a related `B`, which is the opposite of what you want. Using `exclude=True` reverses the logic such that you instead filter for `A`s that have a related `B` instead.

The equivalent `.filter()` calls:

```py
# before, incorrect
A.objects.filter(b=True)

# after, correct
A.objects.exclude(b__isnull=True)
```